# Android Wear - Path w/ Feature

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, sample, disconnect

My question is simple, what does `private static final String PATH_WITH_FEATURE = "/watch_face_config/Digital";` do / point to? Is this supposed to be a folder on the machine? In the app? I think this is why my app is crashing. I'm not getting any IDE errors. But the app tells me there are no android wear devices connected my machine, which is false.

The line of code listed above comes from the demo app, but I can't get that one to run either. Is that path arbitrary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This path doesn't refer to a path on your machine or some folder. Paths are used to identify `DataItem` and `Message` objects, that are part of Data API.

Please read about sending and syncing data here: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html
It should make things clearer.